# mysql filter rows by field value in linked table

Tags: php, mysql

**Scenario:**

I have a main table, say "`items`". Each item can be of many types, and I use a table "`types`" and a linked table to keep the relations between the two, say "`items_types`" in a typical one to many situation. Now, each type has a supertype, with a straight one to one relation.

```
items: i_id, i_name

types: t_id, t_name, t_st_id

items_types: it_id, it_i_id, it_t_id

supertypes: st_id, st_name
```

Now I have to filter all the items that are related to at least one supertype in a given set, say supertypes with ids 1,2,3

I am thinking to use a `group_concat` on the ids of the related supertypes and then filtering using multiple `FIND_IN_SET` in or between each other, using a `WHERE` clause.

However this, if working, would slow down the query and I don't like comparing ids as if they were strings.

Any idea?

Comment: See the folowing guidance on how to ask a good sql question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could provide us with a small sample set of data for the tables, and an example of what your desired output would be.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, it's the first time I post a question here myself. However I have found a better solution to my problem, see below

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
select i.*
from items_types it
join items i on i.i_id = it.it_i_id 
join types t on t.t_id = it.it_t_id
join supertypes st on st.st_id = t.t_st_id and st_id in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution: instead using related records to keep track of all the types the item belongs to, I am giving each type a numeric code which can be used in binary comparison, e.g:

```
Type 1: code 1
Type 2: code 2
Type 3: code 4
Type 4: code 8
Type 5: code 10
```

I think I gave the idea.

Each item will have a field to keep track of all its types, named 'coded_type'. For example if a field has coded_type 7 it means that it belongs to Type 1, Type 2, Type 3.

For instance, if a user then wants to look for all items that are of type 2 or 3 the query will look for all items whose coded_type field binary ANDed against 6 gives a value greater than zero.

That is:

```
select * from items where (coded_type & 6)>0
```

I think this way the query will much simpler and run faster. Sorry I thought of this just now.